Alternating series comparison test
Let's say I have two alternating series of terms,

$(-1)^n A_n$

$(-1)^n B_n$


If I know (by for example Leibniz criteria) that one of the series converges / diverges, can I use comparison criteria to determine that the other one converges / diverges as well? All I could find on the internet is about one series being alternating and the other being positive or not with terms of the form $(-1)^n B_n$.
*Sorry for not formatting the text, first question, don't know how to do so.

As it stands, with no further information, the answer is NO.

The comparison test only works for non negative sums a priori, but sometimes you can get some information using it. For instance, if $A_n$ is absolutely convergent and $A_n>B_n$ for all $n$, then $B_n$ is absolutely convergent as well. In general, with alternating series you are better off using methods such as the Dirichlet test or the alternating series test.

Decreasing alternating series always converges , do you have an example that is not clear and comparison might be of help ?

There are definitely examples where:

$A_n$ is decreasing to $0$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nA_n$ converges; and
$0\le B_n\le A_n$ for all $n$; yet
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nB_n$ diverges.

One such example is $A_n = 1/n$ for all $n$ and
$$
B_n = \begin{cases}
2^{-n}, &\text{if $n$ is odd,} \\
1/n, &\text{if $n$ is even.}
\end{cases}
$$

I had some students once try on an exam to use a comparison test like you dream of in order to show an alternating series converges and I later found a concrete counterexample to this idea on an earlier MSE page here.
My students had tried to prove convergence of
$\sum_{n \geq 2} (-1)^n n^2/(n^3-1)$
by saying $n^2/(n^3 - 1) \sim  1/n$ and $\sum (-1)^n/n$ converges, “so” the original series converges.  This error seems like a plausible mistake to make when series material is new to you.
Here's what they believed, in general terms: if $a_n > 0$, $b_n > 0$, and $a_n \sim b_n$, then the convergence of $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum (-1)^n b_n$.
Here is a concrete counterexample to such a limit comparison test on alternating series, which occurs in a famous Russian problem book on analysis.
Let $a_n = 1/\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n/n$ and $b_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$, so both $a_n > 0$ and $b_n > 0$ when $n \geq 2$ (note $a_1 = 0$) and $a_n \sim b_n$.  But
$\sum_{n \geq 2} (-1)^n a_n = \sum_{n \geq 2} (-1)^n(1/\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n/n) = \sum_{n \geq 2} ((-1)^n/\sqrt{n} + 1/n)$ diverges while $\sum_{n\geq 2} (-1)^nb_n = \sum_{n\geq 2} (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$ converges.

Went to the page, saw my answer... and discovered that I had some exponents swapped and made a rather silly assertion about a limit (now fixed)...
